# Calling a function in a file different from the one where the object is instantiated

Tags: c++

I have three files.

**file 1**
This has the class definition and all the methods in the class are also defined here

**file 2**
The object of the above class is instantiated here

**file 3**
Here I want to call one of the methods using the object created in file 2

I am trying to do above thing is because I want the code to be modular. Is there a better way to do this? Can you post any other solution that you may have?

Comment: It will be helpful to see some code.

Comment: What do you mean by "using the object"?

Comment: It sounds like the object instantiated in file 2 is a global object. Why do you need it to be a global object? Perhaps you can just instantiate it where you need to use it 
(file 3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your definition into an header file (usually .h):

```
//header File1.h
class File1
{
    void Foo();
};
```

Include definition and implement it in another file (usualy .cpp)

```
//File1.cpp
#include "File1.h"

File1::Foo()
{

}
```

Then include the header with the definitions where you want to use

```
//File2.cpp

#include "File1.h"

File1 file1;
file1.Foo();
```

Remember that the 2 translation units must be linked together.